# HTML5 Reading File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to develop an application where it allows the user to choose a file and then read it and display the text on the screen.

My code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/5sy076n5/1/.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FileReader Example</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">



        function testRead() {

            var fileSelector = document.createElement('input');
            fileSelector.setAttribute('type', 'file');

            fileSelector.click();


        }

    </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Example</h1>
        <p>Read <a onClick="testRead();">File</a></p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

You may notice that I don't have an input tag inside the body. This is because I want the user to click on the tag rather than the text.

My problem is what I am suppose to do after fileSector.click();? How can I get what file was chosen?

Comment: Have you checked the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)?

Comment: Yes Yes I know that I have to do that. The only problem is how to use the file system with an a tag

Answer (score -1):

You have already created the input element on runtime and you have the reference of it `fileSelector`

You can simply use this variable to `FileReader` API

```
function testRead() {
    var fileSelector = document.createElement('input');

    fileSelector.setAttribute('type', 'file');

    fileSelector.click();

    fileSelector.addEventListener('change', function () {
        var file = fileSelector.files[0];

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var text = reader.result;
            console.log(text);     // Select *.txt file and see console
        }

        reader.readAsText(file);
    });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5sy076n5/2/)

Comment: Tried it and nothing happens after uploading a document :S

Comment: You have to just select `.txt` file and see the result. What do you mean by _after uploading a document_? The demo is clearly explanatory.

Comment: ah ok.. I tried to open a document sorry my mistake. Can it be done also on documents or only on text files

Comment: What type documents? Here are the [available methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Methods). You can read any binary document data from `readAsBinaryString()` like pdf or you can use https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Comment: Type of documents that I would like to read are .doc and .pdf. When I do with readAsBinaryString, text is displayed as rubbish

Comment: @keithSpiteri Natively it does supports but it will to much pain to read PDF and doc files from binary string and convert into their format. As I suggested, you can use third party libraries for this.

Comment: That is only for textfile and not for doc and pdf

Comment: @keithSpiteri Read your question carefully. **My problem is what I am suppose to do after fileSector.click()**

Comment: See the question: I am trying to develop an application where it allows the user to choose a file and then read it and display the text on the screen.

Comment: @keithSpiteri What I have suggested to you in above comments? You are being specific for `pdf` and `doc` files, which you can find third party libraries easily if you do search.